# Временная кнопка отмены удаления DOM элемента

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго времени суток.
Есть таблица, связанная с SQL. При нажатии на кнопку удаления, которая есть в каждой строке, необходимо скрывать строку и на её месте создавать кнопку с обратным отсчётом и возможностью отмены действия(возвращать строку на место). В случае если кнопка отмены не была нажата, должен отправляться ajax-запрос на удаление этой записи из бд.
Перепробовал множество вариантов и пока остановился на этом, но не совсем то, что нужно.

```
.on('click', '.-deleteItem', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        let id = $tr.data('id');
        let tr = document.getElementById('tr' + id);
        let but = document.getElementById('but' + id);

        console.log(but);
        $tr.remove();
        let rows = $('.-itemsTable > tbody > tr');
        rows.each(function (i) {
            $(this).find('.drag-num').text(i + 1);

        });
        let is = document.getElementById('button');
        is.style = 'cursor: pointer;;display: inline-block';

        let timeleft = 29;
        let sleft = 3;
        let downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
            if(timeleft <= 0){
                clearInterval(downloadTimer);

            } else {
                document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML ="(" + Math.round(sleft) + " c)";
            }
            sleft -= 0.1;
            timeleft -= 1;
        }, 100);

        let data = {token: get_token(), id: $tr.data('id')};
        let min = 3000;
        let timer = setTimeout(time_end, min);

        function time_end()
        {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            let ist = document.getElementById('button').className.indexOf("press");
            if ( ist === -1 )
            {
                is.style = 'display:none';
                console.log('Deleted');
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'orders/deleteItem/',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: data,
                    dataType: 'json',
                }).done(function () {$tr.remove();
                    updateTotalSum();
                }).fail(function () {
                    alert('Возникла ошибка');
                });
            }
            else
            {
                is.style = 'display:none';
                console.log('Returned');
                let profile = document.getElementById('profile');
                console.log(tr);
                profile.appendChild(tr);
                rows.each(function (i) {
                    $(this).find('.drag-num').text(i + 1);

                });
            }
        }


    })
    ;
```

Comment: что-то много кода для такого функционала

Comment: Ну покажи тогда, пожалуйста, как лучше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

что-то примерно такое должно быть

```js
$("table").on('click', ".remove", function(){    
   let row = $(this).closest('tr');
   $(row).addClass('remove-await');
   let h = setTimeout(function(){
              let id = $(row).data('id');
              console.log(`remove: ${id}`);
              //$.post("url-remove", {id: id}, function(){
                    $(row).remove();
              //});
      }, 10000);
      
   let n = 10;   
   let ticks = setInterval(function(){        
        $(row).find(".cancel").text(`cancel ${--n}`);
      }, 1000);
      
   $(row).data({h: h, ticks: ticks});
});

$("table").on('click', '.cancel', function(){
   let row = $(this).closest('tr');
   clearTimeout($(row).data('h'));
   clearInterval($(row).data('ticks'));
   $(row).removeClass('remove-await');
});
```

```css
.remove-wrapper {
   display: none;
   text-align: right;
}
tr.remove-await .remove-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
}

tr.remove-await td:not(.remove-wrapper) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr data-id="1">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td><button class="remove">remove</button></td>
      <td colspan="3"  class="remove-wrapper"><button class="cancel">cancel</button></td>
   </tr>   
   <tr data-id="2">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td><button class="remove">remove</button></td>
      <td colspan="3" class="remove-wrapper"><button class="cancel">cancel</button></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!

Answer (score 1):

Накидал такой вариант, описание в коде

```js
const time = 10; // Время за которое можно отменить удаление (в секундах)
const confirm = document.querySelector('.del-confirm'); // Блок отмены удаления
const progress = confirm.querySelector('.del-confirm__progress-bg'); // Прогресс бар
let parent, timer, // Переменные для хранения удаляемого блока и таймера
    isConfirm = false; // некая "защита", чтобы нельзя было нажимать кнопку "del", если блок подтверждения отображается.

document.querySelector('ul').addEventListener('click', e => { // Делегирование события
    const del = e.target.closest('.del'); // Если нажата кнопка `.del`
    if(del && !isConfirm) { // проверяем ещё и наличие "защита"
    isConfirm = true; // включаем "защиту"
        let i = time; // текущий шаг, начинаем от `time`
        parent = del.closest('li'); // Получаем родительский блок кнопки "удалить"
    
        parent.style.display = 'none'; // сначала прячем удаляемый блок
        confirm.style.display = 'inline-block'; // И показываем подтверждение удаления
        
        timer = setInterval(() => { // Запускаем таймер
            if(i > 0) { // Пока есть возможность отменить удаление
                i--; // Уменьшаем время
        progress.style.width = i / time * 100+'%'; // анимации прогресс бара
            } else { // когда время выйдер
                clearInterval(timer); // очищаем таймер
                parent.remove(); // Удаляем из HTML блок
        parent = ''; // Очищаем переменную (чтобы в ней не хранился блок)
                confirm.style.display = ''; // Скрываем подтверждение
        progress.style.width = '';
        isConfirm = false; // отключаем "защиту"
                // полное удаление
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
});

// Отмена удаления по кнопке
confirm.querySelector('.del-confirm--cancel').addEventListener('click', e => { // вешаем слушатель на клик
    clearInterval(timer); // очищаем таймер
    parent.style.display = confirm.style.display = ''; // возвращаем исходные состояния блоков
    parent = ''; // очистим переменную
  isConfirm = false; // отключаем "защиту"
  progress.style.width = '';
});
```

```css
ul li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

ul li span {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

ul li .del {
  color: #f00;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.del-confirm {
  display: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.del-confirm__progress {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.del-confirm__progress-bg {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffa500;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: width 1s linear;
}

.del-confirm__text {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.del-confirm__btns {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 2em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.del-confirm__btn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>item 3</span>
    <div class="del">del</div>
  </li>
  <li><span>item 2</span>
    <div class="del">del</div>
  </li>
  <li><span>item 1</span>
    <div class="del">del</div>
  </li>
  <li><span>item 0</span>
    <div class="del">del</div>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="del-confirm">
  <div class="del-confirm__progress">
    <div class="del-confirm__progress-bg"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="del-confirm__text">Отменить удаление?</div>
  <div class="del-confirm__btns">
    <div class="del-confirm__btn del-confirm--cancel">Отменить</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а что у вас произойдет при нажатии кнопок удаления в двух разных строках?

Comment: @teran, спасибо что подметили, поправил